# DataContractSerializer with base class in different namespace without attributes

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer

So far I have been reading domain data from an XML file using `DataContractSerializer`.  This is only to get started - I will move onto a database in due course.  There are a lot of domain classes, with a lot of properties, so decorating all of them with attributes specific to the XML deserialization, which would only be temporary, is undesirable.  Up until now, I have gotten things working without having to do so.

I just moved a base class from the domain model namespace/assembly into a common namespace/assembly since it is applicable to other solutions.  This has caused the deserialization to break.  The objects are still created, but nothing is set on the base class.  At first I thought I could solve this simply by passing in the recently moved base type as a "known type" to `DataContractSerializer`'s constructor before calling its `ReadObject` method.  But this didn't help.

Reverting the namespace, but keeping it in the other assembly, makes the problem go away.  But obviously this is not an acceptable solution.  Anyway, it means the problem is the different namespaces.

So what can I do to get the deserialization working again (other than moving the base class back or inserting loads of attributes)?

Comment: Well if you deserialize existing files with the new introduced namespace it will not be able to map it correctly, resulting into empty structures as you have mentioned. I would move the class with the new namespace and then do a global string replace of all the xml files to the new namespace...

Comment: @NeillVerreynne - You got it.  My XML files were actually handcrafted and relied on the default namespace.  I solved it just by defining a new `xmlns` prefix and affixing it to elements from the moved class.

Comment: great stuff, glad you got it working.